# Read one line of a text file in C on Unix — my read_line is broken?

Tags: c, string, unix, malloc, system-calls

I want to make a function that reads a line of your choice, from a given text file. Moving on to the function as parameters (`int fd` of the open, and `int line_number`)
It must do so using the language C and Unix system calls (`read` and / or `open`).
It should also read any spaces, and it must not have real limits (ie the line must be able to have a length of your choice).
The function I did is this:

```
char* read_line(int file, int numero_riga){
    char myb[1];
    if (numero_riga < 1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* myb2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    memset(myb2, 0, sizeof(char));
    ssize_t n;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < numero_riga) {
        if((n = read(file, myb, 1)) == -1){
            perror("read fail");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (strncmp(myb, "\n", 1) == 0) {
            i++;
        }else if (n == 0){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    numero_riga++;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < numero_riga) {
        ssize_t n = read(file, myb, 1);
        if (strncmp(myb, "\n", 1) == 0) {
            i++;
        }else if (n == 0){
            return myb2;
        }else{
            myb2[j] = myb[0];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return myb2;
}
```

Until recently, I thought that this would work but it really has some problems.
Using message queues, the string read by the `read_line` is received as a void string ( "\0" ). I know the message queues are not the problem because trying to pass a normal string did not create the problem.
If possible I would like a fix with explanation of why I should correct it in a certain way. This is because if I do not understand my mistakes I risk repeating them in the future.

EDIT 1. Based upon the answers I decided to add some questions.
How do I end myb2? Can someone give me an example based on my code?
How do I know in advance the amount of characters that make up a line of txt to read?

EDIT 2. I don't know the number of char the line have so I don't know how many char to allocate; that's why I use `*100`.

Comment: One obvious problem is that for `myb2` you only allocate 4 or 8 bytes (i.e. the size of a pointer), which most likely is not enough for your strings.

Comment: [don't case malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: PROBLEM 1: `sizeof (char) != sizeof(char *)`. PROBLEM 2: you really don't want "sizeof *ANY* thing".  You want "max #/characters".  Q: Is there any reason you don't just us [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) (or a buffered equivalent)?

Comment: I forgot I also try change that

Comment: Oh, and you don't terminate the string in `myb2` either.

Comment: I can't use fgets because I do for my teacher

Comment: how can I terminate it?

Comment: @FoggyDay I can't do with fgets. I know I can do with fgets.

Comment: how can I know max #/characters?

Comment: Re: your extra questions: (1) Add a null byte at the end; (2) you can't tell in advance how many characters make up the line.

Comment: A little more specific? like myb2[++j] = '\0'; before return it's ok?

Comment: It would be more normal to use `myb2[j] = '\0';` if, as is normal, `j` indexes the next character to be written.  Can you explain what `numero_riga` is for?  Is it a maximum length of line to read?  Do you want the newline included in the returned string?  Or is the function trying to read line N of the file?  If so your code needs to skip the first N-1 lines and then read and the next?  Do you start counting with line 0 or line 1?

Comment: numero_riga is line number I want to read. if in a txt there are 3 lines and I want to read the second one I pass numero_riga = 2. the function is trying to read line N of the file it start counting from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Partial Analysis

You've got a memory leak at:

```
char* myb2 = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char*))*100);
memset(myb2, 0, sizeof(char));
if (numero_riga < 1) {
    return NULL;
}
```

Check `numero_riga` before you allocate the memory.

The following loop is also dubious at best:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < numero_riga) {
    ssize_t n = read(file, myb, 1);
    if (strncmp(myb, "\n", 1) == 0) {
        i++;
    }else if (n == 0){
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

You don't check whether `read()` actually returned anything quick enough, and when you do check, you leak memory (again) and ignore anything that was read beforehand, and you don't detect errors (`n < 0`).  When you do detect a newline, you simply add 1 to `i`.  At no point do you save the character read in a buffer (such as `myb2`).  All in all, that seem's pretty thoroughly broken…**unless**…unless you're trying to read the N<sup>th</sup> line in the file from scratch, rather than the next line in the file, which is more usual.

What you need to be doing is:

- scan N-1 lines, paying attention to EOF
- while another byte is available

  - if it is newline, terminate the string and return it
  - otherwise, add it to the buffer, allocating space if there isn't room.

#### Implementation

I think I'd probably use a function `get_ch()` like this:

```
static inline int get_ch(int fd)
{
    char c;
    if (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1)
        return (unsigned char)c;
    return EOF;
}
```

Then in the main `char *read_nth_line(int fd, int line_no)` function you can do:

```
char *read_nth_line(int fd, int line_no)
{
    if (line_no <= 0)
        return NULL;

    /* Skip preceding lines */
    for (int i = 1; i < line_no; i++)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = get_ch(fd)) != '\n')
        {
            if (c == EOF)
                return NULL;
        }
    }

    /* Capture next line */
    size_t max_len = 8;
    size_t act_len = 0;
    char  *buffer  = malloc(8);
    int c;
    while ((c = get_ch(fd)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (act_len + 2 >= max_len)
        {
            size_t new_len = max_len * 2;
            char *new_buf = realloc(buffer, new_len);
            if (new_buf == 0)
            {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = new_buf;
            max_len = new_len;
        }
        buffer[act_len++] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n')
        buffer[act_len++] = c;
    buffer[act_len] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Test code added:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *read_nth_line(int fd, int line_no);

…code from main answer…

int main(void)
{
    char *line;
    while ((line = read_nth_line(0, 3)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("[[%s]]\n", line);
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This reads every third line from standard input.  It seems to work correctly.  It would be a good idea to do more exhaustive checking of boundary conditions (short lines, etc) to make sure it doesn't abuse memory.  (Testing lines of lengths 1 — newline only — up to 18 characters with `valgrind` shows it is OK.  Random longer tests also seemed to be correct.)

Comment: I fix some thing. but if I can't know number of char the line have I can't know how many space to malloc

Comment: you have been very helpful